# How to make a good web services?

Tags: java, web-services, jersey

Recently I been reading about SOA, the service oriented architecture is based on the idea of exposing web services.

This Architecture also tells you that the services you create have to be reusable, in other words you have to make universal services.

Now, I have to develop web services for one of my applications, I will use Jersey to develop the web services. I would like to develop web services as I've been reading.

For example, in the login I need to expose a web service. As we can see in the image, the login WebService will receive the id_user and it will response with a status and the password if it exits.

[image: LogIn webService]

The problem is that this web services is not a reusable web service, because it only works for logIn and if, for example, I wanted to check an user's name I would need to create another webservice that will bring me the user's name.

Following what I already now, I change the login web service as follows

[image: UserInfo werbservice]

Now, if I need to logIn, I will use this webServices and just use the password, if I want to load his information I also will use this same web service and use what I need.

With this new web service I just can search using the user_id, so I also change the webService as follow

[image]

I edited the request, now you will need to send the option 1 if you want look for user_id or 2 if you want look for user_name.

I'm wondering if this last change was correct?

I also have another table called bitacora and I need to make a webService for insert and update.

At first I insert data with default values, because the table has foreign key.

For example I will fill my table like follow (1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0) where 0 is the default value for foreign key.

After that I have to update that table changing just a few columns (1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0)
After, I will complete updating my table (1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1).

How can I make a good webService for that need?

As I see, I will need to make 1 web service, and send him in the request the information that I want to update, and an option so I can choose in my web services what to do. (make update 1 or make update 2 or make update 3).

But I think I'm lost in this one.

Comment: Sounds like you are asking for a pattern to use in development of your web service.

Comment: I 'm a little confused, that is why i'm asking for help.

Thanks for the corrections @Peter O. 
I'll do better next time

Comment: I am also asking if I do the correct thing, changing my log in web service into the last one.

Comment: Any web service that serves up passwords is doing the wrong thing. You should look into OAuth2 for authentication / authorisation. If you want to create a 'user' service that manages user-related data then that should be separate.

Comment: Thanks @sisyphus, but what happend with the update / insert ?

Comment: It's a separate concern. Yes, you need to be able to insert / update user information. Passwords are *100%* separate and should *never* be revealed, or even stored in a form which allows them to be revealed. If the question is about update / insert of user data then look to [ReST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer).

Comment: I already make my web services REST using Jersay, if you read my example, i made 3 web services just for update one table. I just want to know if is correct or there is a better way to make this.
Thanks again